# Update Windows local computer description property

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I have a vb script that runs from a wsf file.  It is supposed to set the local computer description by invoking the `net config server` command. This script is executed within MDT for computer deployments. The script runs with no errors in the logs and it does pass the string value to the `%computerdescription%` variable so I have no idea why it isn't updating the computer description field. If I run the command standalone from a command prompt it works ex:

```
cmd /c net config Server /SRVCOMMENT:"%ComputerDescription%"
```

So I am thinking that something in the script is incorrect problematically. Below is the complete script.

```
<job id="ZTISetLocalComputerDescription">
<script language="VBScript" src="ZTIUtility.vbs"/>
<script language="VBScript">
Dim sReturn
Dim sCmd

If oEnvironment.Item("ComputerDescription") = "" Then
    oLogging.CreateEntry "No Computer Description set...", LogTypeWarning
Else
    oLogging.CreateEntry "Computer Description variable set to: " & oEnvironment.Item("ComputerDescription"), LogTypeInfo

    ' Create the cmd to set computer description
    sCmd = "cmd /c net config server /srvcomment:""" & oEnvironment.Item("ComputerDescription") & """ "

    ' Log the cmd we are going to run
    oLogging.CreateEntry "About to run " & sCmd, LogTypeInfo

    ' Set the Computer Description
    sReturn = oShell.Run(sCmd, 1, False)

    ' Log the return code from starting net command
    oLogging.CreateEntry "Return code from " & sCmd & " was : " & sReturn, LogTypeInfo
End If
</script>
</job>
```

Comment: `oEnvironment` and `oLogging` are undefined in the code you posted. Please update your question with a [mcve]. Also show the log your code created.

Comment: Thank you for replying Ansgar.  What I posted is the complete script from beginning to end.  Mysteriously the script suddenly worked. But to answer your questions, both oEnvironment and oLogging are defined as global variables in the source script "ZTIUtility.vbs" listed at the top of the script. This is MDT so all of the scripts in the environment are linked programmatic ally to work together. I have a similar script just as short which calls the same variable as this one and updates the description for the computer object in AD. I don't know scripting very well so that's the best I can expla

Comment: The log is far too long for me to post with the number of characters allowed.  But it's working so I am happy.  Thanks again for replying.